# How to read the row in asp.net in Java script

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net, css

in the below code, there is a image present on second column,if i click on second column i wan to read the data present in first column.

suppose i have 10 rows, if user click on 5 row icon, then i want to read all the details associated with 5th row.

```
    <table class="tableStyle" id="Table1">
        <thead>
              <tr>
                  <th id="Th1" style="background: none repeat-x scroll center top #027DBA;border-left: 1px solid #525252;width:15px;font-weight:bold">
                      <div>Request ID</div>
                  </th>
                  <th id="Th2" style="background: none repeat-x scroll center top #027DBA;border-left: 1px solid #525252;width:15px;font-weight:bold">Request Name
                  </th>
              </tr>
        </thead>
    <%
        for (int i = 0; i < ViewData.Model.Details.Count; i++)
        {
            //String id = i.ToString();

     %>

               <tr>
                   <td headers="Th1" style="background-color:#EFF3FB;border: 1px solid #C1C1C1;color: #000000; text-align:center"><%= ViewData.Model.Details.ElementAt(i).ID%>
                   </td>
                   <td headers="Th2" style="background-color:#EFF3FB;border: 1px solid #C1C1C1;color: #000000; text-align:center">
                        <a href="#"><img style="border:0;" src="/Content/Images/Icon.png" alt="Name" width="20" height="20" /></a>
                   </td>
               </tr>
        <%} 
    %>
</table>
```

Answer (score 3):

Using jQuery, you can attach a click handler on the anchor tag and locate the data by navigating to its parent's previous sibling...

```
$("a").on("click", function (e) {
    var data = $(this).parent().prev().text();
    alert(data);
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

[**JsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/9x9aq/)

Comment: Thanks, but i have one doubt, i dont have js file in my project, i m trying to achieve everything in aspx page itself. how can i add this inside aspx. thanks for your help.

Comment: Thank you, i m able to achieve now. what you have told. But i have one question, prev() will always give me 1st column data if i click on 2nd, Suppose i have 10 columns, and clicked on 5th column and if i want 1st column data, then how to achieve the same?